# Translate table values to text following a fixed pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, translate

We use software to store combinations of financial elements. Those elements are allowed in certain combinations. Exceptions of these combinations are SQL-like statements in the front-end, and are saved as numerical values in a database table like the following example:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 4    | 5    | 1    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| -1   | 2    | 6    | 4    | 5    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 5    | 7    | 1    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I would like to translate those numerical values back to a SQL-statement like the following example:

```
+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
| Col1 | Col1Trans | Col2 | Col2Trans | Col3 | Col3Trans | Col4 | Col4Trans | Col5 | Col5Trans |
+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
| 1    | (         | 2    | SELECT    | 4    | CODE      | 5    | LIKE      | 1    | *         |
+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
| -1   |           | 2    | SELECT    | 6    | NUMBER    | 4    | =         | 5    | AND       |
+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
| 1    | (         | 2    | SELECT    | 5    | TOOL      | 7    | <>        | 1    | *         |
+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
```

The numerical values differ in each column so I can only imagine the use of a lot of case...when statements which I doubt will be efficiënt. I don't want to create tables to hold the translation values. Are there ways to do this with arrays?

Are there any code samples to easily loop through table/columns and translate the contents of it?

Comment: "I don't want to create tables to hold the translation values" Why?

Comment: If you don't have a table to store "translated" values, how else are you going to make them available to whatever code you are writing? By hard-coding them? What's the benefit? Then: it appears that the translation doesn't depend only on the value, but also on the column in which the value appears. Or is your example wrong? 1 is an opening parenthesis in one place, but then an asterisk in another. Is that on purpose, or a mistake?

Comment: @Serg, I don't like creating tables in the db as the db is for this program. Using select-statements only feels better in this case.

Comment: @mathguy, this is on purpose. Every column holds it's own values and translations as this is desined by the program using the DB. If it was up to me, I would do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code and add more case statement as per the requirement.

```
SELECT Col1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN '('
        ELSE '' END AS Col1Trans
    ,Col2
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Col2 = 2 THEN 'SELECT'
        END AS Col2Trans
    ,Col3
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Col3 = 4 THEN 'CODE'
        WHEN Col3 = 6 THEN 'NUMBER'
        WHEN Col3 = 5 THEN 'TOOL'
        END AS Col3Trans
    ,Col4
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Col4 = 5 THEN 'LIKE'
        WHEN Col4 = 4 THEN '='
        WHEN Col4 = 7 THEN '<>'
        END AS Col4Trans
    ,Col5
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Col5 = 1 THEN '*'
        WHEN Col5 = 5 THEN 'AND'
        END AS Col5Trans
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid so many `case when` and `decode` and etc is to use `with as` clause as following:

```
With col1trans (value, translation) as 
(Select 1, '(' from dual union all
Select -1, null from dual),
Col2trans (value, translation) as 
(Select 2, 'SELECT' from dual)
..
... till col5trans
Select m.col1, t1.translation as col1trans,
.... till m.col5, t5.translation
From your_table m join col1trans t1 m.col1=t1.value
join col2trans t2 m.col2=t2.value 
... till col5trans
```

Cheers!!

Comment: @Tesjah, is this better for performance than using so many case when statements? Or what's the benefit? I am not familiar with the with-statement, is this like creating a table in memory in stead of in the db?

Comment: It do not create any table. It is just inline subquery(CTE). But I think for you, it will be good to have it as you can avoid so many case when and oracle do not have to do decision making so many times.